# How can I create an "array" element with sfForm?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

With Zend_Form I could just set an element as an array and it would render with brackets. Can I achieve the same thing using sfForm in symfony?

Comment: Could you please explain your question a bit further? Post some code, explain what do you mean by *render with brackets* etc.

Comment: I don't know about other server side languages, but in PHP, if you have an element that looks like this <input type="text" name="myelement[]"/> 
This will come into the $_POST or $_GET variable as an array. So you could have multiple elements. Very useful for doing something like uploading multiple files in one form among other things.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply set the name of the field to something ending with brackets?